# Passing value in Component Template - knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, components, web-component

I have a component where I'm handling all the errors / error message. I debug it and successfully passed the error string in variable, but I can't display in template

Here is my code

```
export class ErrorHandlerComponent {

get ComponentName() {
    return "error-handler";
}

constructor() {
    this.errorMessage = ko.observable();
    if (!ko.components.isRegistered(this.ComponentName)) {
        ko.components.register(this.ComponentName, {
            viewModel: ErrorHandlerComponent,
            template:
            `
                <div class="modal fade" id="modalError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop='static' data-keyboard='false'>
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;Error occurred</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" data-bind="text: errorMessage">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer modal-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-bind="click: ClickRefreshPage">Refresh</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
        });
    }
}

Show(msg) {
    this.errorMessage(msg);
    $('#modalError').modal('show');
}

Close() {
    $('#modalError').modal('hide');
    $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
    $("body").css({ 'padding-right': '0px' });
}

ClickRefreshPage() {
    alert('refreshing...');
}
```

}

when I call `Show` function, the parameter is passed and `this.errorMessage()` had a value, but in `text: errorMessage` I can't display it.

Comment: for me its clear that `this` refers to wrong context in show function (refers show function itself) can you try using `ErrorHandlerComponent.errorMessage(msg)`

Comment: I got an error saying "errorMessage is not a function" @John Smith

Answer (score 0):

john is right though, `this` refers to the ErrorHandlerComponent at the time of components.register and that is obviously always empty.

What I'm missing is an observable parameter passed through from the parent via the components' `param` property. if you put that in your constructor, ko will link everything through and passing a validationmessage to the component will be displayed.

https://jsfiddle.net/ezw9q02x/1/